# Url Decoding shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, python, url

How can I store the url-decoded string in a variable using shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
alias urldecode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul;print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'
str="this+is+%2F+%2B+%2C+.+url+%23%24coded"

decoded = ${urldecode $str}
echo $decoded
```

I am trying to store decoded string in variable named decoded.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/sh -
urldecode() {
  python -c "import sys, urllib as ul;print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "$1"
}
str="this+is+%2F+%2B+%2C+.+url+%23%24coded"
decoded=$(urldecode "$str"}
printf '%s\n' "$decoded"
```

That is:

- avoid aliases in scripts as that's not guaranteed to work (some sh implementations like bash ignore aliases when non-interactive)
- quote your variables. Leaving a variable unquoted is the split+glob operator in shells.
- The operator to substitute the output of a command is `$(...)`
- variable assignment syntax in Bourne-like shells doesn't allow blanks around `=`, `echo = x` means calling the `echo` command with `=` and `x` as arguments, not assigning `x` to the `echo` variable.
- You can't use `echo` to display arbitrary data, use `printf` instead.

Comment: This does'nt work with python3 :(

Comment: any clue @stephane